# Telerik RadGrid- Adding javascript method to GridEditCommandColumn

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

How can I add a javascript method to the update button of GridEditCommandColumn in Telerik RadGrid?

I need to fire a js method on the update button of EditCommandColumn.
I was able to add clientside event on the edit button but while clicking edit button it turns out to update and cancel. I want to add a js method to this update button.

Please find the column in aspx page below

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following code**

```
<telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditColumn">
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>


Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs)
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim item As GridDataItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)

        DirectCast(item("EditColumn").Controls(0), ImageButton).Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('test')")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this one. The alert box appears on the edit button click. I want to show it in the update button click. (Here the edit button when clicked splits up into update and cancel buttons.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Sikandar. I followed your answer to get the result I wanted.

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem && e.Item.Edit)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            Button btn = (Button)item.FindControl("UpdateButton");
            btn.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirmBox();");
        }
```